# Handling specific php POST data

Tags: php, forms, post

I'm trying to make a small control panel for a little blog system that I am making.
So far, I have managed to pull from the database how many articles there are and the details for each article. With that data I have created the following:

[image]

The code looks like this:

```
    while ($row = $smcFunc['db_fetch_assoc']($request))
    {
        echo '<form action="" method="post" name="blgform">
            <div class="blgdiv">
                <div class="leftdiv">
                <input type="text" value="'. $row['title'] .'" />
                <br>
                <input type="text" value="'. $row['img'] .'" />
                <br>
                <input type="text" value="'. $row['topic_id'] .'" />
            </div>
            <div class="rightdiv">
                <textarea class="desctextarea">'. $row['description'] .'</textarea>
            </div>
            <table class="blgtable">
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#">Unpublish</a></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="javascript: document.forms[\'blgform\'].submit();" name="blgsubmit">Save Changes</a></td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;"><a href="#">Delete Entry</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>';
    }
```

I know how to delete and edit stuff from the database, but I do not know how to make the script run that code for the specific form that needs edit/delete.

I know I need to handle the edited form when POST'ed but it's the whole post/retrieve part that I am unsure of.

I read something about using `if(isset($_POST...` but I am clueless of how to do that, especially in the case of multiple forms like this one.

Also, how to actually POST a form without using a button? I'd rather just have a text-link.

Comment: why so many downvotes? whats wrong with my question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ADD OR UPDATE**

I suggest you use the value of "tropic_id" because it is the only single value. When returning the form, if the form is to add the value must topic_id is empty.

```
<input type="hidden" name="topic_id" value=""> <!-- ADD -->
```

OR

```
<input type="hidden" name="topic_id" value="321"> <!-- UPDATE -->
```

If its for edit, just return it.

Always get a value in the post that will topic_id, but only that you will not empty for editing.

you can check this:

```
// Prevent undefined warning defining topic_id var. 
$topic_id = isset($_POST['topic_id']) ? $_POST['topic_id'] : '';
// then
if($topic_id != ''){
//something like update
}else{
//something like add
}
```

---

**SEND WITHOUT BUTTON**

Use Javascript or jQuery:

Create a link/div/button

```
<div id="IDofyourbutton">Send</div>
```

OR

```
<button id="IDofyourbutton">Send</button>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("IDofyourbutton").onclick = function(){
document.getElementById("IDofyourForm").submit();
}
</script>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '#IDofyourbutton', function(){
$("form#IDofyourForm").submit();
});
});
</script>
```

To use jQuery you need the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/)